# how to convert this ruby on rails code to include html as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I take this..

```
  <li>
  <%= link_to image_tag(product.photo.url(:small)), product_path(product.id, :forum_id => params[:forum_id]) %> 
<% if params[:forum_id] %>
  <%= link_to "Add", addtoforum_user_path(:products => [product.id],:forum_id => params[:forum_id], tp: "add") %>
  </li>
```

to be like this.. (right now it is only inlcluding the image)

```
<li>
   <a href="">
       <figure>
       <img src="image-url....">
       </figure>
       <span>product name</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question but I guess the issue is to output the figure, img tags etc inside the a tag?

This can be achieved by passing a block to the link_to method, like this:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to product_path(product.id, :forum_id => params[:forum_id]) do %>
   <figure>
   <%= image_tag(product.photo.url(:small)) %>
   </figure>
   <span><%= product.name %></span>
  <% end %>
</li>
```